# How and why were different inflections applied to third-person singular verbs in the Early Modern period?

Tags: linguistics, early-modern-english

I can't get my head around why and how inflections were used in Early Modern English. I know that they were used to mark person, number and tense and so on but how and why exactly?

Comment: Do you mean *Why did we used to use **thee, ye** as well as / instead of **you**?* Or more relevant, perhaps, *Why don't we **still** use those forms?* Sounds similar to *Why doesn't English use gendered nouns?*, where to my mind the answer is that English in particular tends to move towards "useful simplification". Largely because no-one *controls* it - unlike the Academie Francais which tries to control French, for example.

Comment: These are questions that historical sociolinguists write dissertations about. There is no single explanation, since nobody was keeping track of how folks were talking and correlating it with their class, age, and place of origin.